# Why does the fact that someone already settled on one way of arranging the "H..." items imply the quantity of H items is irrelevant?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Darrell has a collection of 40 DVDs, each of which contains one movie. There are 17 comedy movies, 14 fantasy movies, and 9 historical movies, where each historical movie takes place in a separate time period. The movies will be ordered on a shelf from left to right so that the movies of each type comedy, fantasy and historical are in a single group of consecutive movies. In addition, the historical movies will be ordered from earliest time period to latest time period. How many possible orderings of the movies are there?

Two Deductions:

1.They never said we have to put 40 on a shelf, but then again it doesn't say we can use half for example.

2. C1F1H1,H1F1C1, whatever they're the same thing. don't double count these.

I think the answer is $(17!)(14!)(9!)$, but the answer key says $(17!)(14!)(3!)$.

Please clarify on the user shellexyz's explanation below

> There is only one way to order the historical movies. While there are 9! ways to arrange them, you have already settled on one way.

> Then there are 3! ways to arrange (comedy) (fantasy) (historical) as groups.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity in the problem statement.  The historical films are to be placed in a particular order, so you don't get a $9!$ term.  And I think it is clear that "The movies will be ordered" means "*All* the movies will be ordered".  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are quoting from a prior problem (on this site or elsewhere), please provide a link.  Otherwise people are likely to simply reproduce what is already written there.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite clear from the language of the question that we have to arrange **all** the 40 DVDs at once; otherwise the answer given in the answer key would never match.

So here we go,

Firstly, the 3 different genres C, F and H can be arranged in 3! ways

Then in each genre,

17 Comedy movies can be arranged in 17! ways

14 Fantasy movies can be arranged in 14! ways

We do not have option to arrange 9 History movies, as it is specified that they have to kept in order of earliest to latest time period. So they can be arranged in only 1 way

Final answer: 3! × 17! × 14! × 1

Comment: Please tell the mistake if you find my answer wrong

Comment: This sounds wrong to me: "*the number of C,F and H type movies must be equal*". . . . also, what does this mean? -> "*First we select the single group that will be repeated throughout the arrangement*"

Comment: Acc to question, in the arrangement of DVDs on the shelf, any 3 consecutive movies must be of the 3 different genres. That can happen only when we fix a set of C,F and H as a unit and repeat that unit throughout the complete arrangement.

Comment: So if CFH (with 3! permutations) is a repeating unit of the arrangement, number of C,F and H movies must be equal (one in each repeating unit)

Comment: It doesn't say "any 3 consecutive movies must be of the 3 different genres". You just made that up.

Comment: Please explain what does the 3rd line of the question mean?

Comment: It means the 17 comedy movies form a single consecutive group, the 14 fantasy movies form a single consecutive group, and the 9 historical movies form a single consecutive group.

Comment: Thanks a lot to clear that! I completely misunderstood it

Comment: I think you're trying to say in the first sentence that to get a unique answer we have to assume all the $40$ movies have to be arranged, but the reference to the answer key is making this unclear.

Comment: If the number of movies of each genre is not fixed (we have the choice of taking as many as we want), then the number of ways of selecting C movies would be 2¹⁷, F movies could be selected in 2¹⁴ ways; similarly H movies could be selected in 2⁹ ways. We would subtract the case of completely empty selection. Now we would arrange them first genre-wise and then internally permutate each set. Which becomes very messy; but the answer given in the answer key indicates that the author had taken ALL 40 DVDs at once; as only then we would get that answer.